# ZF2 Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found

Tags: filter, zend-framework2, locale

I am using ZF2 2.1.5 and trying to use the `Alnum` filter `Zend\I18n\Filter\Alnum`.
I have the php_intl extention enabled in my local wamp server but still getting the error :

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in [root]\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\I18n\Filter\Alnum.php on line 76
```

what should i do?

Comment: Certainly an error with the extension then. For testing purpose, try calling `$loc = \Locale::getDefault();` and see if the class can be loaded at all. If not it's absolutely an extension / server problem

Comment: i should have mentioned that i am using win7x64 , probably this is the problem ... acording to apache error log : <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found. but the file is in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the solution here :
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,80704,82499

> So, one solution is to add "[path]\wamp\bin\php\php#.#.##" (or similar
>   directory) to your system PATH.
>
> The other solution is to copy the icu*.dll files to your apache's bin
>   directory.
>
> A third option is to copy the icu*.dll files to your Windows system
>   directory (system32 or SysWOW64).

I used the second option.

Comment: thanks +1. The solution adding the path to system path is best (save some disk space ;) )